# Test generated by angular CLI fails if in a specific folder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6, zonejs

I've generated a component in my components folder using the angular CLI (v6.1.4) by running `ng g c components/foo` and have then run `ng test`. The test for the new component fails with the following errors:

> Zone is needed for the async() test helper but could not be found. Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/dist/zone.js thrown
>
> Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive FooComponent.

Oddly, if I run `ng g c foo` (i.e. so it's not generated in the components folder), the test then passes. My tests are all working for other folders, but this is the first test in my components folder (and is also the first test for a component). None of the other tests are asynchronous.

I'm fairly new to `ng test` so I might be missing something very obvious. I wasn't expecting to need to set up anything with `zone.js` for the default test to run. Where should I configure this? Or is there something else I'm missing here, perhaps something specific to my `components` folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the following to the top of `foo.component.spec.ts` fixed the issue, but I still don't understand why the tests worked if they weren't in the `components` folder. If someone has an explanation, or a solution that doesn't involve repeating this in every component's test file, I'd love to hear it!

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case here, I wondered if my project might have been generated with a different version of the main test configuration, so I created a new empty project with Angular CLI, compared both versions of `src/test.ts` and I realised that this file was indeed different, my app was missing the following line as the first one:

`import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing'`

After adding it to the `src/test.ts` file, this error was gone!

This is probably way better than importing all those js files to all specs as Tim's answer suggests.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. In my case, that line is already in `src/test.ts`, and if I remove the 5 imports from a test file then the tests break again. I've never managed to understand this problem unfortunately.

Comment: @Tim, have you tried comparing your test to a newly created angular app?

Comment: In my case that line was also in test.ts, but it was not the first line. I moved it all the way up and now tests run fine. Thanks, @BrunoJCM !

Answer (score 0):

In adition to [@BrunoJCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535504/test-generated-by-angular-cli-fails-if-in-a-specific-folder#:%7E:text=at%2011%3A43-,BrunoJCM,-1%2C94819) [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535504/test-generated-by-angular-cli-fails-if-in-a-specific-folder#:%7E:text=import%20%27zone.js/dist/zone-testing%27) which solved my issue by organizing the imports on **test.ts** file, bear in mind the following settings in your project might make you run into the problem again, so *concerning the **test.ts** file, check the following*:

1. Deactivate onSave optimize imports.
2. Avoid running [Prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier), [Beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/beautify) or other code style formatter that reorganizes the imports (either package or plugin).
3. Check for pre-commits hooks like [Husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) that formats the files and reorganize the imports.

Enjoy hassle-free coding! :D