# Error: zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found. When running test on Angular webapp using serenityJS+Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, serenity-js

I am trying to run component testing on Angular web app using serenityJS + Jasmine but encountered the error below. Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Message:

> Error: zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found.
> Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js
> Stack:
>
> ```
>    Error: zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found.
>            Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js
>        at resetFakeAsyncZone (C:\Users\zhenweiwong\Desktop\serenityjsframework\packages\core\testing\src\fake_async.ts:25:9)
>        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zhenweiwong\Desktop\serenityjsframework\packages\core\testing\src\before_each.ts:26:5)
>        at <Jasmine>
>        at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
>        at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:131:23)
>  Message:
>    Error: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js
>  Stack:
>    Error: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js
>        at new NgZone (C:\Users\zhenweiwong\Desktop\serenityjsframework\packages\core\src\zone\ng_zone.ts:129:13)
>        at TestBedViewEngine._initIfNeeded (C:\Users\zhenweiwong\Desktop\serenityjsframework\packages\core\testing\src\test_bed.ts:409:9)
>        at TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (C:\Users\zhenweiwong\Desktop\serenityjsframework\packages\core\testing\src\test_bed.ts:599:10)
>        at Function.TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (C:\Users\zhenweiwong\Desktop\serenityjsframework\packages\core\testing\src\test_bed.ts:245:36)     
>        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zhenweiwong\Desktop\serenityjsframework\jasmine-test\spec\app1.component.spec.ts:32:29)
>        at <Jasmine>
> ```

Comment: I have the same problem but using Jest instead of Jasmine, have you ever find a way to fix it?

Comment: @ghiscoding [the top-voted answer at the present time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68797535/6243352) works in Jest for me (importing `"zone.js"` and `"zone.js/testing"` at the very top of the `setupJest.ts` file). Angular 12/Jest 27/TS 4.2 environment.

Answer (score 61):

Hello little bit late to answer but I leave the comment here for future reference:

**ERROR ORIGIN**

In my case, the error was found in the **test.ts** file. This file sets the TestBed config that is used by default in Angular spec files when created with the command **ng generate component my-component**.

**SOLUTION**

The fix is to make sure that you **place** the following **imports** at the **TOP of the file
test.ts** before any other import:

```
// Top of test.ts file
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/testing';
```

Be careful with your configurations that might alter the order of those imports as it may lead to break the tests again. That's why you might, over the **test.ts** file:

1. Deactivate onSave optimize imports.
2. Avoid running [Prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier), [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) or other code style formatter that reorganizes the imports.
3. Check for pre-commits hooks like [Husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) that format the files and reorganize the imports.

**FURTHER TROUBLESHOTING**

You might also want to look if the following imports are present:

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
```

Same issue was solved with other approaches in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535504/test-generated-by-angular-cli-fails-if-in-a-specific-folder#:%7E:text=In%20my%20case,Tim%27s%20answer%20suggests.).

Comment: you might need to use `import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';` instead of `import 'zone.js/testing';` & it should be on top of all the imports (it worked for me while the other one kept generating the error `Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found.`) according to this link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/40977#issuecomment-785800709

Comment: Thanks buddy u saved my day, I have placed `import 'zone.js/testing';` at top in test.ts and it worked for me

Comment: Had the same issue on my side with an Angular v14 project. The `test.ts` file only had the `'zone.js/testing'` import and moving it on top of the file fixed my issues.

Comment: After updating to Angular 17 I had the same issue, and it was due to previously having `import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';` So the solution worked here, and should be marked as the solution (might not be a global solution, but it was a solution for the actual problem).

Answer (score 23):

I got the same issue after upgraded from the Angular 10 to Angular 12. Then I fixed it by move the `import 'zone.js/testing` to the top of the file `test.ts`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

In Vscode open file ***test.ts***.

Add line down on top file, ***first line***.

```
import 'zone.js/testing';
```

OBS: if your vscode organize your imports there file, use o **organize-imports-disable-next-line**.

Example:

```
import 'zone.js/testing';
// organize-imports-disable-next-line
```

[See more](https://github.com/trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports/issues/112)

Comment: It's confusing that you "disable" the next line, but put the thing that needs to be disabled a _above_ the disable comment. Either way though, it works. My tests started breaking after I added the organize imports option. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems that you can just use a blank line between `import 'zone.js/testing';` and all other imports, rather than this disable command

Answer (score 9):

### Angular 15

I ended up here after getting a similar issue in my app after upgrading from Angular 14 to Angular 15. I solved it [this way](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3/pull/2054/commits/13c11ad1ab1457d8e0189d4eeb34507a412e1f08) by:

1. editing the `angular.json` file and in the project `"test"` changing its `"options"` by removing `"main": "src/test.ts",` and adding this instead:

```
"polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
```

2. the `src/test.ts` file can now be deleted

Answer (score 8):

This issue comes into picture from Angular v11.

**Solution:**
Move `import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';` to the top in `src/test.ts` file.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same issue by adding
`import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';` in `setupJest.ts` which is used in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: './jest.preset.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "<rootDir>/setupJest.ts"
  ],
...
```

I am using Angular 14 with Jest@^28.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using Angular `waitForAsync`.

Instead of:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations: [BannerComponent]}).compileComponents();
});
```

Try to use the following:

```
import { waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations: [BannerComponent]}).compileComponents();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this error because of syntax,

**From**

```
beforeEach(async(async () => {
   await TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations: 
         [ListComponent]}).compileComponents();
 }));
```

**To**

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations: 
          [ListComponent]}).compileComponents();
});
```