# How to fix zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I'm having this error when trying to run e2e tests with protractor in my angular 12 application,

```
   - Failed: zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found.
              Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/testing
```

I've already tried the solution mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67414283/error-zone-testing-js-is-needed-for-the-fakeasync-test-helper-but-could-not-b) but with no luck.

This error only occurs when I try to import something (like enums) from a library (developed with angular 8) in the e2e tests files.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

[Edit] This only happens after upgrade to angular > 11